# dmb.error when looking up data, I need some pointers

Tags: python, dbm

I have a dbm file that leads to an error when I try to access a value directly:

```
>>> import dbm
>>> db = dbm.open('scrapers','c')
>>> key1 = db.keys()[0]
>>> db[key1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
dbm.error
>>> db.get(key1)
'(dp1\nS\'username\'\np2\nNsS\'password\'...etc...
```

It only happens with this file, it contains pickled classes of scrapers to various websites.

I can't provide the actual db data because it contains login data.
My question is: what are *possible* explanations for this problem? Where should I start looking to debug this?

If you need any other info (except for the data itself) please let me know.

Comment: try opening with `flag='c'`. Check `len(db.keys())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a detail to dbm that isn't explained in the python dbm docs:

```
The sum of the sizes of a key/content pair must not exceed the internal block size (normally between 512 and 4096 bytes).
```

I'm using `gdbm` now, and this works just fine.